# Ruby URI - How to get entire path after URL

Tags: ruby, parsing, uri

How do you get the full path of the URL given the following

```
uri = URI("http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413")
```

I just want `posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413`

I tried uri.path and that returns /posts and ui.query returns 'id=30&limit=5'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask the `URI` object for its `path`, `query`, and `fragment` like this:

```
"#{uri.path}?#{uri.query}##{uri.fragment}"
# => "/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413"
```

or (a little more consice, but less explicit):

```
"#{uri.request_uri}##{uri.fragment}"
# => "/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413"
```

Comment: Worth noting that when there's no query or fragment, this could generate valid but perhaps undesirable results like `"/foo?#"`.

Answer (score 17):

The method you are looking for is [`request_uri`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/HTTP.html#method-i-request_uri)

```
uri.request_uri
=> "/posts?id=30&limit=5"
```

You can use any method you'd like to remove the leading `/` if needed.

Edit: To get the part after the `#` sign, use `fragment`:

```
[uri.request_uri, uri.fragment].join("#")
=> "/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413"
```

Comment: Thanks.  But, this is missing #time=1305298413

Comment: I would `[uri.request_uri, uri.fragment].reject(&:blank?).join("#")` to avoid unwanted # at the end.

Comment: the fragment is not sent to the server BTW in an usual scenario where the uri comes from a web request

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an artsy solution, for completeness – others may be more reasonable :)

```
uri.dup.tap { _1.scheme = _1.user = _1.password = _1.host = _1.port = nil }.to_s
```

Though a benefit of this solution is that it also handles `URI::Generic` like you'd get from parsing a standalone path:

```
uri = URI.parse("/foo?bar#baz")  # => #<URI::Generic /foo?bar#baz>
```

Solutions that rely on `URI::HTTP#request_uri` won't work with `URI::Generic`. So if you're writing code that accepts both full URLs and paths, that may be a factor.

Answer (score -1):

```
File.basename("http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413")
# => "posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413"
```

Comment: doesn't work for subroutes like `http://foo.com/posts/likes?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413`